Cancel pending pd.read_sql_query in python asyncio
I'm running SQL queries on several databases asynchronously with asyncio. I want to set a timeout after 1 second of execution, and get the result of the SQL queries that succeeded in time, without waiting for the others.
Here is an example with a very fast query and one long query:
import asyncio
import functools
import logging

import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine1 = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost:3306/my_db1")
engine2 = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost:3306/my_db2")

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


async def run_query(query, engine):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        await loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(pd.read_sql_query, query, engine))
        logger.info("query over")
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        logger.warning("long running query cancelled !")


async def main():
    done, not_done = await asyncio.wait(
        [
            asyncio.create_task(run_query("SELECT 1", engine1)),  # Fast query
            asyncio.create_task(
                run_query(
                    # Long running query
                    "select benchmark(100000000, md5('when will it end?'))",
                    engine2,
                ),
            ),
        ],
        timeout=1,
    )


logger.info("starting")
asyncio.run(main())
logger.info("all done !")


Output:
2024-08-02 11:19:02,098 :: __main__ :: INFO     :: starting
2024-08-02 11:19:02,105 :: __main__ :: INFO     :: query over
2024-08-02 11:19:03,100 :: __main__ :: WARNING  :: long running query cancelled !
2024-08-02 11:19:41,146 :: __main__ :: INFO     :: all done !

As expected, the function executing the long query receives the cancel call after 1 second. But the script continues to wait for it to be completed.
I can't find a way to force it to stop. Am I missing something here ?
